# MAA Monthly vs. AMS Bulletin

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals

What is the difference between the two journals (MAA Monthly and AMS Bulletin)? Are they basically for the same thing?

I am considering writing a nice exposition to summarize some of my recent work. My results are closely related and should be of interest to a wide audience, but are currently spread across several papers in specialized journals.

Is there any difference in the expected level of technicality, or demand for formal proofs? In the article I would not want to give standard proofs, but only explain the key ideas and show how the results contribute to a broader theory.

Finally, what is the effect of having an article published in one of these journals? Will it be worth my efforts?

Comment: Umm what are the journals?... you shouldn’t assume everybody on here knows what they would be. You should also probably read the journals to see what the differences are.

Comment: in my title please

Comment: Have you read them both?  The styles of articles they usually publish are extremely different.

Comment: The *Monthly* does not publish original research, so do not even bother sending it to us there.

Comment: @GEdgar: The *Monthly* most certainly does publish original research.  To choose one example of **important** research that was published there: Bhargava, Manjul
The factorial function and generalizations.
Amer. Math. Monthly 107 (2000), no. 9, 783–799.

Answer (score 11):

[The American Mathematical Monthly](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly) (which is I think what you call the MAA Monthly; often abbreviated AMM) is an expository journal at a level slightly above undergraduate -- i.e., it is a journal for mathematical papers (and problems!) that most mathematicians can understand (as opposed to specialized papers written for experts in a specific topic).

[The Bulletin of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/all_issues.html) (short BAMS) is a graduate-level and research-level expository journal.

In theory, there can be overlap between the scope of the two: An exposition that is sufficiently elementary to be understood by undergraduates, yet sufficiently novel that it is of interest to researchers, could be published in either journal. (For example, various parts of combinatorics come to mind.) Also, both journals publish papers on the history of mathematics sometimes.

The American Mathematical Society also has another expository journal, called [Notices of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/notices), but it does not directly compete with the AMM either; it is more focused on brief (proof-less) surveys for researchers than on anything suited to undergrads. It also focuses on contemporary issues of the mathematics community.

Comment: Bull AMS isn't a regular journal for research papers.  https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/aboutbull: "The Bulletin publishes expository articles on contemporary mathematical research, written in a way that gives insight to mathematicians who may not be experts in the particular topic."  These are usually survey papers that focus mostly on discussing existing results.  Sometimes there are new results, but only incidentally.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Oooops, I was basically talking of JAMS and PAMS the whole time! Thanks for spotting this. Fixed (hopefully reasonably -- it turns out I don't know BAMS very well.)

Comment: I don't think you're describing the *American Mathematical Monthly* entirely accurately.  You call it an undergraduate level journal.  While it is closer to that than most other math journals, that is *not* part of its description or mandate: see https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly.  Rather it is supposed to appeal to a broad mathematical audience.  On the other hand there is the *College Mathematics Journal*, which does have that explicit mandate: https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I'm saying undergraduate-level (as in, understandable by good undergraduates), not specifically concerned with undergraduate education (which CMJ would be a better fit for indeed). Am I still getting AMM wrong?

Comment: @darij: In my opinion: a bit yes, though it gets subtle.  First of all I don't think CMJ concerns undergraduate mathematics *education* (that is a separate academic field) but rather has articles that may be of pedagogical interest to undergraduates.  The *Monthly* is actually the **highest level** journal published by the MAA (there is also **Mathematics Magazine** as well as several journals that publish pieces that are, somehow, even lighter).

Comment: It would be a **great** undergraduate who could page through an issue of the *Monthly* and understand the majority of articles: such people certainly exist but compromise a small minority of the *Monthly* readership.  To stick to what I know: I have published three articles/notes in the *Monthly*, and I would not describe any of them as at the undergraduate level *per se*.  Two of them are pretty close and one is (I think) less so: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Euclidean_Criterion_homepage.pdf.  The *Monthly* publishes a lot of articles like this (making use of graduate level algebra).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I've made more changes; is the description better now? I have indeed taken the German concept of "undergraduate" (*Vordiplom*) for a reference, and it is not very close to the US notion. Still, it would be even wronger to speak of the AMM as a graduate-level journal. As to CMJ, it's written for teachers rather than students (just look at the titles: the word "classroom" is being used all the time), although the papers may well be a better fit for self-learning (there's a bit of a misconception going around about how much spare time lecturers have in their classes).